# using ELF weak symbols to enable a feature if two other features need it

Tags: gcc, elf, weak

I'm developing a static library (*.a file) with GCC and an ELF target.

I need the following (*AND12* setup):

- the *data* part must be linked into the executable iff both features *feature1* and *feature2* are linked in (because they are used)
- *feature3* should be able to detect whether *data* was linked in

Is there a way to do this using weak symbols or some other tricks understood by GCC and GNU ld(1)?

---

FYI I was able to implement this (*OR12* setup):

- the *data* part must be linked into the executable iff either feature *feature1* or *feature2* is linked in
- *feature3* is able to detect whether *data* is linked in

Here is how I did it:

```
/* data.c */
const char data[] = "RealData";
```

```
/* f1.c */
#include <stdio.h>
extern const char data[];
void feature1() {
  printf("feature1 %s\n", data);
}
```

```
/* f2.c */
#include <stdio.h>
extern const char data[];
void feature1() {
  printf("feature2 %s\n", data);
}
```

```
/* f3.c */
#include <stdio.h>
__attribute__((weak)) extern const char data[];
void feature3() {
  printf("feature3 %s\n", data);
}
```

```
/* main.c */
void feature3(void);
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  (void)argc; (void)argv;
  feature3();
  return 0;
}
```

```
/* main1.c */
void feature1(void);
void feature3(void);
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  (void)argc; (void)argv;
  feature1();
  feature3();
  return 0;
}
```

```
/* main2.c */
void feature2(void);
void feature3(void);
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  (void)argc; (void)argv;
  feature2();
  feature3();
  return 0;
}
```

```
/* main12.c */
void feature1(void);
void feature2(void);
void feature3(void);
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  (void)argc; (void)argv;
  feature1();
  feature2();
  feature3();
  return 0;
}
```

It works like this:

```
$ gcc -c -O2 -W -Wall -Werror f1.c f2.c f3.c data.c && rm -f f123.a && ar crs f123.a f1.o f2.o f3.o data.o
$ qq xstatic gcc -s -O2 -W -Wall -Werror main.c f123.a && ./a.out
feature3 (null)
$ qq xstatic gcc -s -O2 -W -Wall -Werror main1.c f123.a && ./a.out
feature1 RealData
feature3 RealData
$ qq xstatic gcc -s -O2 -W -Wall -Werror main2.c f123.a && ./a.out
feature2 RealData
feature3 RealData
$ qq xstatic gcc -s -O2 -W -Wall -Werror main12.c f123.a && ./a.out
feature1 RealData
feature2 RealData
feature3 RealData
```

What I want to get is the following (different from the above for main1.c and main2.c):

```
$ gcc -c -O2 -W -Wall -Werror f1.c f2.c f3.c data.c && rm -f f123.a && ar crs f123.a f1.o f2.o f3.o data.o
$ qq xstatic gcc -s -O2 -W -Wall -Werror main.c f123.a && ./a.out
feature3 (null)
$ qq xstatic gcc -s -O2 -W -Wall -Werror main1.c f123.a && ./a.out
feature1 (null)
feature3 (null)
$ qq xstatic gcc -s -O2 -W -Wall -Werror main2.c f123.a && ./a.out
feature2 (null)
feature3 (null)
$ qq xstatic gcc -s -O2 -W -Wall -Werror main12.c f123.a && ./a.out
feature1 RealData
feature2 RealData
feature3 RealData
```

How should the library files *f1.c*, *f2.c*, *f3.c* and *data.c* be modified so that it works like as above?

Please note that I'm only interested in a setup where the linker is able to figure it out correctly when to include the *data*.

I'm not interested in manual workarounds in which the *main* function passes additional information to the *feature...* functions, for example when only *main* has `extern const char data[]`, and it passes it to *feature...* functions as arguments.

I'm not interested in a workaround where the *data* is always present in the executable (*OR12* setup), and *feature1* and *feature2* detect the presence of teach other, and they ignore the *data*  unless both of them are present. (That's because the *data* is huge, and it's wasteful to store and ship something which is not needed.)

I know about and for the purposes of this question I'm not interested in workarounds where the *data* is stored outside the executable, e.g. in a separate file, which is shipped to the end user only when neded.

It's also OK for me if the solution has code instead of *data*, because the code can also contain and return data.

---

How is this useful? *data* is huge, and it is an implementation detail of the library, and it is only needed by library features *feature1* and *feature2* if both *feature1* and *feature2* are used. For maximum convenience, the user expects that the linker is able to figure out automatically what to include in the final executable. The user doesn't want to have *data* included when not needed (because it would make the final executable too large unnecessarily), and they also don't want to manually track whether it is needed (because the user builds several versions of the executable, and the dependencies are deep down in user code).